# GridView, setting drawable for item

Tags: android, gridview

I try to make multichoice in my GridView with this code:

```
ArrayList<String> selectedItems=new ArrayList<String>();

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

...

    GridAdapter gridAdapter = new GridAdapter(this, tmp);

    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            String code=((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.code)).getText().toString();
            int index=selectedItems.indexOf(code);
            if(index==-1) {
                view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.selected);
                selectedItems.add(code);
            } else {
                view.setBackgroundDrawable(null);
                selectedItems.remove(index);
            }
        }});

...

}
```

But this have a problem. I click one of item, it change color to gray, that's ok. Then I scroll down my GridView and see another item with gray color. But it doesn't checked in actual fact and I never click it. Why? How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I fix it when put in GridAdapter.getView() this code:

```
if(selectedItems.contains(code))) {
    convertView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.selected);
} else {
    convertView.setBackgroundDrawable(null);
}
```